# notation for set of integers divided by m?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, integers

Sorry if this is a bad question but I was asked to prove the rules for exponents (such as a^x*a^y = a^(x+y))
but I didn't quite understand the notation our professor used.

He says to
"Deduce those laws for elements α ∈ Z/mZ and k1, k2 ∈ Z≥0."

I'm not quite sure what he means by Z/mZ. I googled it and all I could figure out was that it has something to do with the modulus operator. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does have to see with moduli: $\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z$ is the set of (classes of congruence of) integers modulo $m$. $m\mathbf Z$ denotes  the set of multiples of $m$, and two integers are congruent modulo $m$ if their difference is an element of  $m\mathbf Z$.

By the algorithm of Euclidean division, this also means $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder upon division by $m$.

Comment: Does this mean the set would just include the integers 0, 1, 2....m-1?
because a mod m would have to be less than m?

Comment: $a\bmod m$ is a *representative* of the congruence class, which is the set $a+m\mathbf Z$. Each congruence class has a unique representative between $0$ and $m-1$.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb Z/m \mathbb Z$ is [the ring of integers modulo $m$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n).